# When to start testing a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, bdd

I really like the idea of TDD and BDD testing with rspec and cucumber, however I'm not entirely sure when to start those things with a new app. I don't want to start too early because it seems like not that great of an idea, but at the same time I don't want to expand the app too much before I start testing.

So my question is - when to start writing tests?

I'm planning on making a simple app with Rails and would want to use all the best practices I've learned about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you said about "starting too early" some development strategies (ie [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)), one of the first things you do is write tests, the tests will obviously fail, and then you write the code that makes the tests pass.  This way you can clearly define what you want your app to do (and not do).  Some [studies](http://nparc.cisti-icist.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/npsi/ctrl?action=shwart&index=an&req=5763742&lang=en) have found this approach to be highly productive.

Comment: Thank you, so I've heard. I was just confused, if it's okay to start writing tests when I barely have any controllers or models in place. I've also heard that writing too many tests can be a bad thing. But thanks again for your comment, it cleared things up for me a bit.

Comment: Well, you don't want to get caught up in doing nothing but writing tests.  Like most things in programming, you just need to find what works best for you (or do exactly what your company tells you to do ;))

Answer (score 1):

@JTG is right, with the caveat that if you don't know understand what you're going to develop, which happens early on for many, you may need to develop without tests at first. This helps programmers early on to learn about their environment and what's involved in the build process.

If you do not write tests before you develop, you can go back and write those tests, alter the code so the tests fail, then change it to make them pass. This is not the best way to move forward once you know what you're doing, but can be an acceptable workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Well, provided answers are great, but if you say that you like the idea of TDD it means you like writing tests **first**(and some other TDD ideas).. That is why I am a little confused about your question (sorry if I misunderstood you). Anyway here is what I think about it: Don't be afraid of writing tests at the very beginning. According to TDD you write test just for you next development step. So at start it is very likely that your tests are simple. One for example may just expect an action to return successful response. Then you make it pass implementing controller and the action, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I was just unsure if tests being so simple at the very beginning is an okay thing. But now I get it. Thank you.